# Как изменить цвет текста в AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема когда включена темная тема кнопки не видно (нужно чтобы они были белые)

```
Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Обновить или выйти?")
                .setNeutralButton("Обновить" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        recreate();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Выйти", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                    {
                        finishAndRemoveTask();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
```

Проверяю темную тему так

```
  if (currentNightMode==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {}
else
{}
```

Comment: Проще создать свой item и вызывать его как Alert_Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
Заменил   
new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
 на     new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertTheme)

<style name="AlertTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#212121</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#212121</item>
```

Результат устроил